# Why this error? "no appropriate default constructor available"

Tags: c++

Someone has given me the following C++ code snippet to try out - and now I have lost contact with them (its a long story). Anyway, it won't compile - I get an error

> error C2512: 'mstream' : no appropriate default constructor available

Can anyone explain why, and what is needed to fix it.

```
class mstream : private ostream
{
  public:

  mstream& operator << (char *value)
  {
    printf ("[%s]\n", value);
    return *this;
  }
  mstream& operator << (int value)
  {
    printf ("[%u]\n", value);
    return *this;
  }

};
mstream g_mcout;
```

**EDIT: Oops, missed this out...**

```
ostream& mcout ()
{
  return g_mcout;
}
ostream& SgDebug ()
{
  return g_mcout;
}
```

**FYI:** the reason for this strange looking code is all to do with merging a C++ with a C program. The printf()'s will actually be changed to my_printf()'s which do a wide variety of custom things.

Comment: Is that the whole definition of the `mstream` class?

Comment: For next time, please use the question "subject" for a meaningful subject description. This one is funny: "Beginner" doesn't matter, SO is for everyone. "question": Every question on SO is a question. "C++": Already mentioned in the tag.

Comment: @chiccodoro: Point taken. See new subject.

Comment: Why are you subclassing `ostream` and then using `stdio`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ostream` has no default constructor; the implicitly created default constructor for `mstream` is invalid because of it. You need to provide the `ostream` with a stream buffer:

```
class mstream : private ostream
{
public:
    mstream() :
    ostream(/* whatever you want */)
    {}

    /* Maybe this is more appropriate:

    mstream(std::streambuf* pBuffer) :
    ostream(pBuffer)
    {}

    */

    // ...
};
```

So it can construct. What you put there depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

`mstream` inherits from `ostream`, which is a `typedef` for class template `basic_ostream` specialized on `char`.  Since you don't define a constructor for `mstream` the compiler will attempt to provide one using default constructors for `ostream` to initialize the base class.

However, `basic_ostream` has no default constructor (with no parameters), so you **must** provide an `mstream` constructor with suitable inputs for the base class constructor.  Your choices of how to construct the base class are :

```
explicit basic_ostream(
    basic_streambuf<_Elem, _Tr> *_Strbuf,
    bool _Isstd = false
);
basic_ostream(
    basic_ostream&& _Right
);
```

and the first is the most sensible choice for you to use, for example like so:

```
class mstreambuffer : public streambuf
{
public:
    mstreambuffer() : streambuf()
    {
    }
};

class mstream : private ostream
{
public:
    mstream(mstreambuffer* buff) : ostream(buff) {}
};

int main(void)
{
    mstreambuffer buff;
    mstream g_mcout(&buff);
    g_mcout << 32768;
    return 0;
}
```

`mstreambuffer` is necessary because `streambuf` is abstract.

btw besides being uncompilable, this code also uses CRT (`printf`) instead of more usual C++ output via `cout`, so it's doubly suspect.  Prefer this:

```
  mstream& operator << (int value)
  {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a default constructor as said because you're trying to create an instance.

```
class mstream : private ostream
{
    public:
    mstream()
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/ostream/ for details of the arguments to pass.

Comment: yep, constructors don't need a type.

Comment: -1 not helpful. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64308/try-xyz-answers

Comment: That question has -9. Humm... nice reference :p

Comment: @Johannes: You and I seem to be in the rare group of "empower over patch". I don't understand why, you'd think we should try to give people knowledge to solve their own problems, learn how to get information and apply it elsewhere, and overall improve their critical thinking skills in the domain instead of just patch up their work, but apparently most SO people don't agree. It's pretty stupid.

Comment: @GMan: I do hint only when it seem an school question. However SO is about answering question, not teaching. However I do agree with you that giving people tools is better than solving their issues. Sometimes answering a question gives the tools; obviously I just hinted here.

Comment: @Wernight: I strongly disagree it's about answering questions and not teaching, but like I said I'm a minority here. People would be much better of if they understood the problem and knew how to solve it than just copy and pasted answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your parent class (`ostream`) doesn't have a default constructor, so your `mstream` class's constructor must manually construct the ostream parent as well.

Answer (score 0):

`std::ostream` is a typedef:

```
typedef basic_ostream<char, char_traits<char> > ostream;
```

Then `std::basic_ostream<>` does not have a default contstructor, only this:

```
explicit basic_ostream(basic_streambuf<Elem, Tr> *strbuf);
```

So you need to call the constructor of the base class explicitly L

```
mstream(): ostream( pointer_to_some_implementation_of_streambuf ) { ... }
```